# Is it possible/plausible to mimic the MS Project Server 2007 Project Server Interface?

Tags: project-server

I have a web app that manages a significant amount of project data. I don't want to use MS Project Server. We already have a server side application that is specific to our needs. It would be nice if MS Project 2007 could read and write some of the project data. From my reading of the docs, MS Project 2007 communicates with Project Server via the Project Server Interface (PSI). The PSI is relitively well documented on msdn ... so, I was wondering if it would be possible for my web app to impliment the Project Server Interface so that it can talk natively to MS Project 2007?

Is this a good idea? Why/why not? Has anybody done it, or tried? Are there libraries that I could use? Is there any easier way to achieve the same effect using a planning tool other than MS Project? It can't be a little ultra light project tool - I'm talking projects with 6000 + scheduled tasks.

On the server side I am running PHP with the Zend Framework and Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so emulating PSI is technically plausible, but a massive amount of work, and so not practical. Using the Java library MXPJ is a better option for transfering MS Project data in and out of an application.